# How to extract 7zip file from IBM Data Science Experience Notebook

Tags: data-science-experience

Silly question, but being unable to install 7zip from the notebook, and not having access to the underling system, I am here stuck with different 7zip archives obtained via `wget` which I am not able to extract.

Also I would like to avoid the obvious option of downloading archives locally, and eventually upload data unzipped or in different formats, not really a process I can automatize easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but an idea:
[DSX allows to install custom libraries](https://datascience.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/importing-libraries.html). You could try to install `py7zlib` which is able to decompress 7zip archives:

```
!pip install --user py7zlib
```

An later something like

```
myfile=open(filename,"rb")
archive = py7zlib.Archive7z(myfile)
data = archive.getmember(archive.getnames()[0]).read()
```

Comment: I was aware of the custom libraries installation option, but initially understood that there was no way to work on 7zip files from python, and most suggested instead to simply call the tool from command line. Thanks to your feedback I saw instead that there are different options: py7zlib, libarchive, lzma. Nothing worked for me nevertheless so at the end I relied on _wgetting_ a portable version of 7zip, as explained [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-extract-a-7-Zip-file-using-the-7-Zip-portable-version)

Answer (score 1):

Tested and worked for me

```
#for windows users :
pip install --user pyunpack
pip install --user patool

#for ubuntu users :
sudo pip install pyunpack
sudo pip install patool

from pyunpack import Archive
Archive('YourFile.7z').extractall("your/path/")
```